# Выбрать элементы списка по индексам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте.
Есть список `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
и произвольный список индексов, к примеру
`keys = (0, 3, 4)`.
Как проще и правильнее выбрать из списка l элементы по индексам из keys? В результате нужен список [1, 4, 5] ну или что-то такое.
Пока вижу такой вариант `print([v for k, v in enumerate(l) if k in keys])`, но может есть что-то лучше?

Comment: `print([l[i] for i in keys])`, если проверять индексы: `print([l[i] for i in keys if i >= 0 and i < len(l)])`

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо, действительно проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например:

```
print([l[i] for i in keys])
```

Если проверять индексы:

```
print([l[i] for i in keys if i >= 0 and i < len(l)])
# OR:
print([l[i] for i in keys if 0 <= i < len(l)])
```

Comment: Спасибо, красиво.